# Pipelining between an unknown amount of processes

Tags: c, unix, pipeline

According to my understanding, I don't need to know the number of pipelines ahead (although I can, I implement it using a linked list). I have a structure called `cmdLine`:

```
typedef struct cmdLine
{
    char* const arguments[MAX_ARGUMENTS];
    int argCount;
    char const *inputRedirect;
    char const *outputRedirect;
    char blocking;
    int idx;
    struct cmdLine *next;
} cmdLine;
```

And here's the function to execute (only the part of the code that matters):

```
void execute(cmdLine *pCmdLine)
{
    int status = 0;
    int fd[2];
    pid_t id;

    if(pCmdLine->next)
    {
        if(pipe(fd) == -1)
        {
            perror("Error opening pipe.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pCmdLine->idx == 0)
        {
            dup2(fd[1], 1);
            close(1);
            close(fd[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            close(0);
            dup2(fd[1], 1);
            close(1);
        }
        execute(pCmdLine->next);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        waitpid(id, &status, 0);
    }

    id = fork();

    if(id == 0)
    {
        if(execvp(pCmdLine->arguments[0], pCmdLine->arguments) == -1)
        {
            perror("execvp failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    if(pCmdLine->blocking)
    {
        waitpid(id, &status, 0);
    }
    if(pCmdLine->next)
    {
        execute(pCmdLine->next);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
    }
}
```

Basically, if it's the first command I close the input pipe (as it can't get any input) and replace `fd[1]` with the `stdout` so when I activate `execvp()` the next time it gets the input from the previous command executed and the output goes to the next up until it's the last command - when it only gets input and closes output pipe. I don't understand where the problem is, when I type something like `ls -l | tail -n 2` it prints the long-listing of the WHOLE folder and then it is stuck (as if getting input - although I enter lots of input and nothing happens as preparing for segmentation fault).

What is the problem? How do I fix this? I think I'm not in the right direction at all, and I really need help with this.

Comment: You need to close old file descriptors after dup2

Comment: @JEnsMunk before or after?

Comment: After dup2, it doesn't close old descriptor.

Comment: @JensMunk It doesn't solve his problem though.

Comment: Which exact values do the `cmdLine` list members have that are passed to `execute()`?